# Can someone explain this Pulsate code to me

Tags: xna, mathematics, xna-4.0

```
// Pulsate the size of the selected menu entry.
double time = gametime.TotalGameTime.TotalSeconds;
float pulsate = (float)Math.Sin(time * 6) + 1;
scale = new Scale(1 + pulsate * 0.05f,1 + pulsate * 0.05f);
```

I grabbed it from the XNA GameState sample and just curious.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like it's using a sine wave to change the scale of an object. Sine ranges from -1 to +1, so adding one to the `pulsate` variable puts the range at `0` to `2`. Then adding 1 to `(pulstae * 0.05f)` Puts the [range at 1 to 1.10](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%281%20%2b%20%281%2bsin%28x%29%29%20*%200.05%29%20from%200%20to%202pi).

As the name implies, this would likely give the appearance of pulsating.

Multiplying the time by 6 compresses the sine wave on the x-axis. Making the pulsing happen faster. If you were to multiply it by a smaller number (or not multiply it by anything) you could slow the pulsing.

[image: sine wave]

Comment: Why do they multiply the time by 6 ?

Comment: Multiplying the time by 6 will change the speed at which the pulsing happens. Basically it shrinks the sine wave on the x axis. Pulsing faster.

Comment: How can I relate it to the frequency?

Comment: Faster = higher frequency.

Comment: so the 6 correlates to a pulse every 1/6 seconds?

Comment: @Setheron: No, `sin(t)`'s period is 2PI seconds, so `sin(6*t)` gives you a pulse every 2PI/6 seconds, which is slightly less often than once a second.

Comment: See the link I posted for showing the range. Since x is your seconds elapsed, the x-axis shows seconds. In that example, you get about 1 full pulse per 6 seconds. You can play with that to see the change in speed of the pulse. Basically `sin(6*tSeconds)` is about 1 pulse per second. And Eric is correct with his comment.

Comment: @Eric I think you mean slightly more ;)

Comment: @Setheron: A pulse every ~1.05 seconds is slightly less. :-)

Comment: Yep, if it takes a little more than 1 second, then it will happen slightly less than once per second.